# How to solve a Critical NoneType error with pelican?

Tags: python, invoke, pelican

When I do the command `invoke build` in my blog folder, I have the following output :
`CRITICAL: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.

I tried to install a theme named [Flex](https://github.com/alexandrevicenzi/Flex) by downloading it, so I added the following line in my pelicanconf.py file as described in the [git documentation](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes):
`THEME = "/myPath/Blog/pelican-themes/Flex"`

If I remove the line, the command `invoke build` runs correctly.

I’m using pelican 4.5.0 with Python 3.8.5 and Invoke 1.4.1. Does anyone have an idea about the source of the error ?
Thanks

Comment: It might be necessary to give some more context for this. Posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in particular would be a huge help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much to add.The process is pretty straightforward, I installed Pelican, tested with success. I added the theme as described in my post and ran into the issue. I'll add the source of the theme in my post, it might help.

Comment: Did you find out the solution? I'm running into the same issue with Flex theme. I tried pulling new changes to Flex github repo, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: No, sorry. I've moved to Nikola blog, it appears that most of the themes are not up to date and you're likely to run into issues.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue when using the Pelican-elegant theme.  It was easier to track down the error by running with the verbose and Debug option enabled using 'pelican -v -D'. The Plugin architecture changed for version 4.5 and the default setting for PLUGINS was set to none. For the Pelican-elegant theme, a [fix](https://github.com/Pelican-Elegant/elegant/pull/640/commits/491228fd694c2a18e42cd59d7375f013f39571e7) was submitted. There may be a similar issue with the Flex theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a similar issue with Flex. Fixed it by running 'pelican -v -D' as above and then adding 'PLUGINS and ' to the start of every 'if' that generated an error. This has been driving me mad for two weeks!